# Unable to import mysql table to hadoop using sqoop

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to import table from mysql table using sqoop, but I am getting error no database found.

While running the following command:

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/EOD  --username xxx --password xxx --table sqoop --target-dir /data/small/book2


java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'EOD'
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'EOD'
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:193)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:162)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'EOD'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4612)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1296)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2412)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2445)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2230)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:813)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:620)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:200)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getConnection(DBConfiguration.java:294)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:187)
    ... 10 more

13/11/28 10:55:03 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputlocalhost.localdomain
13/11/28 10:55:03 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputlocalhost.localdomain
13/11/28 10:55:03 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201311271328_0011_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'EOD'
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:167)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:722)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'EOD'
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:193)
    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:162)
    ... 9 more


I am able to get the list of databases using below command.

    sqoop list-databases --connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost" --username xxx --password xxxx
```

BTM

EOD

Please can any one help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the root exception is this one:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'EOD'
```

That is suggesting that the database you are connecting to do not exists. I would suggest to verify your JDBC URL. It would be also very helpful if you could attach entire `Sqoop` log generated with parameter `--verbose` next time.

Another quite suspicious fact is using "`localhost`" as your database host. Considering that `Sqoop` will be connecting to your database from possibly all nodes in your `hadoop` cluster, using "`localhost`" is usually not the right thing to do.

Comment: Use of actual IP of the network helps in this situation instead of localhost 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

try: `sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EOD  --username xxx --password xxx --table sqoop --target-dir /data/small/book2`

specifying the port in which your mysql is listening to is necessary especially when using localhost.